# Documentation to create a custom area on map for addresses on Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to create a custom area on a map,
so that when a user enters their address I would be able to determine if that address is in that custom area?

Not too sure what to search in the documents as I keep coming up with "Custom style markers, Custom maps etc."

Mapboxjs for website

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is what is traditionally called a "point in polygon lookup". The address is the point, the "custom area" is the polygon, you want to know if the point is in the polygon or not.

Assuming the polygon is not too complex, you can simply create it in GeoJSON (say, with geojson.io), then use turf's [booleanPointInPolygon](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon) function to do the test.